# Where can I find gtkglextmm for centos 6?

Tags: centos, package-management, yum

Yet another "where can I find" question.

I'm looking for gtkglextmm, the gtk/gl C++ wrapper, for CentOS 6. On my Ubuntu system, I know you can get it with `sudo apt-get install libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2-dev` but I can't find an equivalent package for yum.

I've tried grabbing the source (from [here](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkglextmm)) and compiling that with `./configure` then with `make`, but I get an error saying `/usr/lib/libGL.so: could not read symbols: file in wrong format` I've always been weak with understanding compiler errors and how to fix them...

So, can someone either direct me to a precompiled rpm for gtkglextmm, or tell me what I need to do to compile the source?

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just extract the Package from Ubuntu or Debian and copy these files manually? There doesn't seem to be a complex package structure. I know, I would hate to do this, too, but...

Comment: That's possible? I thought the packages were compiled for each system specifically...

Comment: You are right. When I saw "-dev", I made the wrongful connection to "source code"...

Comment: Easiest way for "how to find" questions is to run ./configure and if a check fails it will usually tell you which file is missing in config.log - you can easily search for that file in all packages via `yum whatprovides */filename` or by your favorite package search engine. Even easier if you know one filename that should be provided by the missing package. Just keep in mind for library filenames to omit major/minor numbers (.so.version at the end) as they might slightly differ on CentOS compared to Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it our myself.

I went with trying to build the library, and discovered a couple issues with libGL. One, my libGL.so was pointing to a folder that didn't exist. Two, being on a 64 bit machine, libGL.la was referencing /usr/lib, when my libraries are in /usr/lib64. So, I changed the last line to lib64, and tried `./configure`. Bam. It worked. Ok.

Now I just need to build the actual application I'm trying to install...